# Can I run my script using inputbox to appear my menu-box before login?

Tags: scripts, upstart

I am trying to do experiment with `/etc/init`. I have written a script which displays a window showing some menu. I don't understand on which event I should start my service.
I don't want any desktop manager after booting so I disabled LightDM. Now I want that my script should execute to show my own menu after booting. How can I achieve this?? 
Please help.....
I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

This is my script

```
  dialog --backtitle "Linux Shell Script Tutorial " --title "Main\
  Menu" --menu "Move using [UP] [DOWN],[Enter] to\
  Select" 15 60 3 \
  Date/time "Shows Date and Time" \
  Calendar "To see calendar " \
  Editor "To start vi editor " 2>/tmp/menuitem.$$

  menuitem=`cat /tmp/menuitem.$$`

  opt=$?

 case $menuitem in
 Date/time)  date;;
 Calendar)    cal;;
 Editor)       vi;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any chance to run such a script during booting or **before** login screen. The reason: you must to be authorized/authentified to run commands like `vi`. If you wish, you can run that script **on/at** (immediately after) login. See [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) in this sense.

Files in `/etc/init` are configuration files telling Upstart how and when to start, stop, reload the configuration, or query the status of a service.

Comment: I added my script in /etc/init.d , and made a symlink of my script with /etc/rs2.d, And thats showing me a dialog box but that is in background process, I didnt know about this but during booting that dotted animation with UBUNTU word appeared and when I pressed arrow key (Up) then I saw that output of my script. But I very confused now, what should be the next step.

Comment: @Kishor You will end probably with a broken system if you continue like this.

Comment: I know that . Please suggest me Is there any solution to meet my requirements?

Comment: can I achieve this by using xinit ??

Comment: Well, see `man xinit`.

Comment: Got success with xsession. Now I can run my script without login and desktop manager. Thank you for your help.
Feeling happy.. :)